# Find a vector $x$ such that: $\min c^{T}x$ subject to $Ax = b$ and $x\ge0$, with constraints.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

The definition of a linear program is following:

Find a vector $x$ such that: $\min c^{T}x$, subject to $Ax = b$ and $x\geq0$.

Generally, $b$ is assumed to be a fixed constant. However is it possible to construct a program where values of $b$ are part of the optimization? Could I included $b$ in the optimization by changing $Ax = b$ to $Ax-b = 0$. If so, would I also be able to place constraints upon $b$ like $\sum{b} = 1$ and $1>b>0$? Finally, would such a program be possible to solve efficiently?

I am trying to solve the linear program for Wasserstein Distance between two discrete distributions. In the standard case, b represents the marginals for each datapoint. I know the marginals for the target distribution but the marginals from my source distribution are unknown. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to optimize the marginals for my source distribution such that the Wasserstein distance is minimized.

Comment: the standard linear program has $\ge$ inequality, not strict ones. The overall response is yes but I am not sure what you are exactly looking for here? what is the ultimate goal here?

Comment: That description would be good context to include in your post, (what you wrote before my second to last comment) @indispinablenorm !  Seriously.  It provides improved context for your question!  In fact, you can copy and paste your last comment, into your question post.  I can do that for you, if you want me to do that.  I won't change a word.

Comment: I added "with constraints" in the title. The linear program is covered in the tag.  I was just trying to write a title, which together with your tags, gives users, scanning a long list of question, enough reason to click on the question; particularly those who favorite any tag you used.  Your edit is great.

Comment: @amWhy! Thanks for the advice! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: There is no solution in general since $x>0$ is open.

Comment: If $b$ is a variable along with $x$, the constraint $Ax = b$ can be written as $\begin{bmatrix} A & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ b \end{bmatrix} = 0$. Additional constraints on $b$ can be handled as well. It can be a bit awkward to write your linear program in “standard form”, as you are doing here. LP solvers typically allow you to have equality constraints of the form $Ax = d_1$ and inequality constraints of the form $Cx \leq d_2$ (where $x$ is the optimization variable).

Answer (score 1):

If you want $b$ to be variable, yes, you can move it to the LHS and change the RHS to $0$.  An optimization modeling language would perform such transformations on your behalf.  If you are instead directly using a solver that requires one constraint matrix and constant vectors for the objective and RHS, you will need to explicitly augment the matrix and vectors to accommodate the new variables.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the reply. Is there an optimization modeling language you recommend? I am currently using python to solve this.

Comment: I use the OPTMODEL modeling language in SAS, which has a Python interface.  What LP solver are you using?

Comment: @indispinablenorm If you're not a SAS person, CVXPY is worth considering.

Comment: Hi Rob, I am using POT to solve for EMD. I believe they are using a network simplex algorithm, calculating min flow to solve the problem. I tried using scipy.linprog but that gave me memory issues while CVXPY takes a long time to solve. Weirdly, POT doesn't take that long to solve. I am dealing with 50000 source nodes and 10000 destination nodes. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Are you able to share your code and data?

Comment: Hey Rob, I can. Would you like the code for my implementation of it in CVXPY or Scipy?

Comment: Maybe provide both.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rDTh4V49, let me know if you have any trouble understanding the code

Comment: Hmm, I think the more important part is the raw data.  And you are trying to solve the problem given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance#Theory)?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes! I am trying to solve EMD but I also want to optimize over the marginals in my source distribution.

Comment: Hi Rob, the raw data is simply a feature embedding of the MNIST dataset after running through resnet 50. The cost matrix is calculated by pyTorch